# Get information from a MySQL database for a time period given a date

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a simple database such as this:

[image: database]

How could I retrieve an employees total number of sales from their current year given their starting date in a single query?

For example, an employee gets added with a start date of the 1st of March 2015. The period between the 1st of March 2015 - 28th of February 2016 is their first year, and the date between the 1st of March 2016 - 28th of February 2017 is year two etc.

So if a query was run on the 5th of March 2017, it would return the data between the 1st of March 2017 and the 5th of March 2017 because that is the current year. Similarly if the query was run on the 13th of February 2017 it would return all sales between the 1st of March 2016 to the 13th of Febuary 2017 because that would be their current year.

Currently, the only way I can get this working is by retrieving the started date for the employee in one query, taking the month and day from the year, checking if the date has already passed this year and then forming a new year start date that way. Such as this:

```
//Get the year start date for the employee
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("select StartDate from employee where EmpID = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($empID));
$employee = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$dateArray = explode("-", $employee['StartDate']);

//If the current month and day is greater than the start date then its not been the end of the year, so the start year is the current year -1
//If not then it has not gone past the end of the year, and the start year is same as the current year.

if (date('m') <= $dateArray[1] && date('d') <= $dateArray[2]){
    $yearStart = (date('Y')-1)."-".$dateArray[1]."-".$dateArray[2];
}else{
    $yearStart = date('Y')."-".$dateArray[1]."-".$dateArray[2];
}
```

Then I could query the database again to retrieve all sales from the generated year start.

The above works, but is it possible to get this into a single MySQL query?

Comment: SELECT DATE_ADD(StartDate , INTERVAL 365 DAY)as YearCompleteDate from employee where EmpID=?;

Will get you the end date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat complicated date arithmetic.  You need to compare the month/day of the sales date to the month/day of the start date.  Then, you need to determine if the year needs to be the current year or the previous year.

The following expresses this logic, assuming that the sales dates are not in the future:

```
select e.empId, count(*), sum(amount)
from employee e join
     sales s
     on e.empId = s.empId
where (date_format(now(), '%m-%d') >= date_format(e.startdate, '%m-%d') and
       s.date >= str_to_date(concat_ws('-', year(now()), month(e.startdate), day(e.startdate))
      ) or
      (date_format(now(), '%m-%d') < date_format(e.startdate, '%m-%d')
       s.date >= str_to_date(concat_ws('-', year(now()) - 1, month(e.startdate), day(e.startdate))
      )
group by e.empId
```